# Delete rows if there are null values in a specific column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, series

[image]

I'm new to python pandas. Need some help with deleting a few rows where there are null values. In the screenshot, I need to delete rows where `charge_per_line == "-"` using python pandas.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If the relevant entries in Charge_Per_Line are empty (`NaN`) when you read into pandas, you can use `df.dropna`:

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Charge_Per_Line'])
```

If the values are genuinely `-`, then you can replace them with `np.nan` and then use `df.dropna`:

```
import numpy as np

df['Charge_Per_Line'] = df['Charge_Per_Line'].replace('-', np.nan)
df = df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['Charge_Per_Line'])
```

Answer (score 6):

Multiple ways

1. Use str.contains to find rows containing '-'

   ```
   df[~df['Charge_Per_Line'].str.contains('-')]
   ```
2. Replace '-' by nan and use dropna()

   ```
   df.replace('-', np.nan, inplace = True)
   df = df.dropna()
   ```